# Send variable through 2 forms with servlet

Tags: java, forms, jakarta-ee, servlets

I got a problem with 2 servlets. Basically I got 1 jsp page with form, when I click on submit, i need to get all variables from this jps, in order to inject them into the second on (input type="hidden"), for finally submit all together.

My servlet 1 (Add client)

```
    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("salut 1  ");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/JSP/Template/BankAdvisor/AddClient.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    String city = request.getParameter("city");
    String zipcode = request.getParameter("zipcode");
    String phone = request.getParameter("phone");

    if (firstname != null && lastname != null && email != null && address != null && city != null && zipcode != null && phone != null) {

        if (!lastname.isEmpty() && !firstname.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !address.isEmpty() && !city.isEmpty() && !zipcode.isEmpty() && !phone.isEmpty()) {

            request.setAttribute("firstname", firstname);
            request.setAttribute("lastname", lastname);
            request.setAttribute("email", email);
            request.setAttribute("address", address);
            request.setAttribute("city", city);
            request.setAttribute("zipcode", zipcode);
            request.setAttribute("phone", phone);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/BankAdvisor/AddAccount").forward(request, response);

        } else {

            response.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/BankAdvisor/AddClient");
        }

    } else {

        response.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/BankAdvisor/AddClient");
    }

}
```

My servlet 2 (Add account)

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/JSP/Template/BankAdvisor/AddAccount.jsp").forward(request, response);
    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    String city = request.getParameter("city");
    String zipcode = request.getParameter("zipcode");
    String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    String city = request.getParameter("city");
    String zipcode = request.getParameter("zipcode");
    String phone = request.getParameter("phone");

    //The two news variables
    String accountName = request.getParameter("accountname");
    String accountType = request.getParameter("accounttype");

    if (firstname != null && lastname != null && email != null && address != null && city != null && zipcode != null && phone != null) {

        if (!lastname.isEmpty() && !firstname.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !address.isEmpty() && !city.isEmpty() && !zipcode.isEmpty() && !phone.isEmpty()) {

         // ACTION 
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/BankAdvisor/AddClient");
        }

   } else {
 response.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/BankAdvisor/AddClient");
   }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In servlet 1 you should use :

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/BankAdvisor/AddAccount").forward(request, response);
```

instead of :

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/BankAdvisor/AddAccount").forward(request, response);
```

because with [`ServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29), if the path begins with a "/" it is interpreted as relative to the current context root (i.e. context path of the current request).

- Example : if you received a request on `http://test/myapp/toto` it will forward on `http://test/myapp/toto/BankAdvisor/AddAccount`

Whereas with [`ServletContext#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) path is interpreted as relative to the current context root (i.e. context path of the current web application).

- Example : if you received a request on `http://test/myapp/toto` it will forward on `http://test/myapp/BankAdvisor/AddAccount` if the webapp context root is `http://test/myapp`

Comment: How exactly does that make difference in this particular case? If it really solved the OP's problem (given the fact that the answer is currently marked accepted), then the real cause should surely have been somewhere else.

Comment: The `response.sendRedirect()` lines in OP's code only don't confirm this.

Comment: True, but I think these redirect calls won't work either. If I'm not mistaken it should be `response.sendRedirect("/BankAdvisor/AddClient")`